# Placing button on Bottom right corner of jsp page

Tags: html, css, jsp

I want to place button on bottom right corner of page. I am trying to place this without using any external CSS in JSP page. The topmargin and leftmargin does not work. The button position is at the same place.

```
    <table topmargin="30" leftmargin="50">
    <tr>        
    <td><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeWindow();" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Can someone please point me in right direction on this. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use that inside the table, then you can design in such a way that last row last column should have the the button. Or if you are trying fo page in general try the below code

```
<div style="position:absolute;bottom:10px;right:10px; z-index:999" >
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="yourFunction();" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi It worked, but it changed the code above it. The positioning of a button placed in a table above it shifted.

Comment: <tr>                                    <td><p><spring:message 
                 code="wcsslabel.lastname" />***<spring:message 
                code="wcsslabel.colon" /></p></td>
                    <td><form:input 
                   path="lastName" maxlength="35" size="35" /></td>
               </tr>
 
                             <tr><td>     <input type="submit" value="submit">  
 </td></tr>                                                                                        The submit button in this code automatically went to the top right after adding div tag in below table.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```html
    <div style="position:absolute;bottom:0;right:0" >
    <table>
    <tr>        
    <td><input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closeWindow();" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```